# Android plugin is disabled

Tags: android, plugins, scripting

Code in the build.gradle.kts file such as:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.bluromatic"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.bluromatic"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.2"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.05.01"))
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1")
    implementation("androidx.test:monitor:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.5")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    implementation("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3")
}
```

Error:
warning: default scripting plugin is disabled: The provided plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
error: unable to evaluate script, no scripting plugin loaded

How can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

In your app level gradle file changing compileSdk and targetSdk to 33 would help. Because SDK version 34 is not stable yet.